# Grammar of __PRETTY_FUNCTION__

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, grammar

GCC offers `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` ([6.48 Function Names as Strings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html)) which is a string with function name.

---

For example following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace n1
{
namespace n2
{

template<typename T>
class t1
{
public:
    template<typename R>
    R f(T const&) const noexcept
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        return {};
    }
};

}
}

int main()
{
    n1::n2::t1<std::string>{}.f<double>(std::string{});
}
```

when build with

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++14
```

on my `g++ (GCC) 7.2.0` (MinGW), produces following output:

```
R n1::n2::t1<T>::f(const T&) const [with R = double; T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
```

---

Now, the question is - where can I find grammar corresponding to this string. Obviously it is C++ based since there are components (identifiers for example) that come from C++, however entire string definitly is not a valid C++ so it cannot be found in C++ specification.

Is it specified anywhere?

I guess it is not (after all above mentioned link doesn't say it...). However, maybe at least it could be read from sources - where would I find those?

Comment: It's a GCC extension, which is why you can't find it in the C++ Standard.

Comment: @MSalters, yes, I know this. Non the less, I would like to know the grammar of this string.

Comment: It is not defined in gcc documentation, most likely on purpose. It may change from version to version.

Comment: @n.m. How to read it from sources of gcc?